# How to insert data into swing table whose columns are dynamically defined (data from a mysql database)?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I have a table and on a opening of a frame the table receives its columns and their respective headers from a table in mysql database. How can i insert all the values from the sql database table into the swing table??
Here is my code...

```
DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
String query1=null;
try    {
  query1="select * from "+Variables.table+";";
  ResultSet rsft=st.executeQuery(query1);  
  Object o[]=new Object[x];  
  while(rsft.next()) {                
    for(int i=1;i<=x;i++){
      o[i-1]=rsft.getString(i);
    }
    dtm.addRow(o);
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
}
```

In above code x is an integer denoting the number of colums in sql table.
And Variables.table is a static variable containing the table name.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getColumnCount` will still return 0, despite that you added some rows.  Just call `setColumnCount` as well.

You can verify this in the source code, or just perform a quick test, e.g.

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class DefaultTableModelDemo {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    defaultTableModel.addRow( new Object[]{"Test", "Test"} );
    System.out.println( "defaultTableModel.getRowCount() = " + 
       defaultTableModel.getRowCount() );
    System.out.println( "defaultTableModel.getColumnCount() = " + 
       defaultTableModel.getColumnCount() );
  }
}
```

gives the following output

```
defaultTableModel.getRowCount() = 1
defaultTableModel.getColumnCount() = 0
```

It might be easier to just create a data vector first, and then create a new `TableModel` and replace the existing `TableModel` of the `JTable`.

Further remarks:

- Since the `dtm` is already used for a `JTable`, you should only update it on the Event Dispatch Thread. But database connections/queries are typically "slow" and should not be performed on the EDT. You can avoid this by either wrap each of the `addRow` calls in a `SwingUtilities#invokeXXX` call or just construct a new `TableModel` on the background thread and replace the model in one go on the EDT. Consult the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.
- Do not forget to `close` the `ResultSet` in a finally block